# Load Resource returns null with Jboss7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x

How do I load resources like images from the java code with Jboss7.1?

This used to work with Jboss4:

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/myapp/includes/images/image1.png");
```

Now this returns null.

What is best practice for loading resources in java code now with Jboss7?

I did some testing:

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("");
System.out.println(url);
url = this.getClass().getResource("../../../");
System.out.println(url);
url = this.getClass().getResource("../../../../");
System.out.println(url);
url = this.getClass().getResource("../../../../../");
System.out.println(url);
url = this.getClass().getResource("includes");
System.out.println(url);

13:33:49,143 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) vfs:/C:/Eclipse/apps/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments/my-ea.ear/my-web.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/xxx/yyy/beans/jsf/
13:33:49,144 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) vfs:/C:/Eclipse/apps/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments/my-ea.ear/my-web.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/xxx/
13:33:49,150 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) jar:file:/C:/Eclipse/apps/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/modules/javax/activation/api/main/activation-1.1.1.jar!/com/
13:33:49,151 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) file:/C:/Eclipse/apps/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/modules/sun/jdk/main/service-loader-resources/
13:33:49,152 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) null
```

Comment: Are you trying to load resources located in the file system? Is this necessary, or can you package them in the `war`?

Comment: The image I'm trying to load is packaged in the WAR file. I keep it in "WebContent/includes/images/".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [documented](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToPutAnExternalFileInTheClasspath) on the JBoss community wiki (without using a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file):

1. Create a module for the configuration file (`jboss-as-7/modules/com/yourcompany/configuration/main/module.xml`):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.mycompany.configuration">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="."/>
    </resources>
</module>
```

2. Add properties to the module:

```
jboss-as-7/
   modules/
      com/
         yourcompany/
            configuration/
               main/
                 module.xml
                 settings.properties
                 other-settings.xm
```

3. Add the module to the `CLASSPATH` using a `MANIFEST.MF` entry:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Dependencies: com.mycompany.configuration
```

4. Load a properties file from the CLASSPATH:

```java
InputStream settingsStream = 
  getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("settings.properties");
```

I had to create a module folder called `com/mycompany/main` and add all the images in there. So this sits outside the WAR at least though within `JBOSS_HOME`. Then I could load the image using:

```
URL imgUrl = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("myimage.jpg");
```

Answer (score 3):

The method `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("path")` is handling the *path* from the root of your classpath. In a WAR this is normally `WEB-INF/classes` and `WEB-INF/lib`.

Your path `WebContent/includes/images/` seems to be inside the root of your WAR file (which is not the classpath). So you can

- use `getResourceAsStream` of `ServletContext` (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29)) which handles paths to the root of the WAR file.
- package all of your images in a additional JAR (e.g. `my-app.resources.jar`) and use `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()`
- move your images in the classpath (see above).

Answer (score 0):

The class loading in JBOSS 7 is based upon JBOSS module project. All earlier versions loading is in a hierarchical manner.

In earlier versions of JBOSS we can put/specify the external folder containing all the app properties in the classpath attribute by modifying run.sh/run.bat.

But in JBOSS 7 since the loading is based on JBOSS module project, the external properties configuration is different.

You can try configuring/loading the properties file in JBOSS 7 in below two ways,

1. Prepare jar having all the property files required for your app. Use
   this jar in your war/ear.

   Then any property file from this jar can be loaded using below code,

   InputStream inputStream =     Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName) ;
2. The changes required in JBOSS 7 to specify external property files is available in community link https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToPutAnExternalFileInTheClasspath. If the changes are done according to this link, deployment will work. Make sure after configuration in JBOSS 7, the below code has to be used to load properties,

   InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("xyz.properties");