# getResourceAsStream() returns NULL under JBoss 7.1 but OK with Tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss

I am trying to access a file that is located in the WEB-INF folder.  In particular, I have the following line of code in the init() handler of a servlet:

```
InputStream s = servletContext.getResourceAsStream(sPath);
```

where

```
sPath = File.separator+"WEB-INF"+File.separator+"filename.ini";
```

I have been running this under Tomcat 7 with no problem but I am trying to switch over to JBoss 7.1 and with no other changes the same code now returns a NULL. Can someone explain why this is failing under JBoss when it used to work under Tomcat?

Thank you,
Al

Comment: I think this is a difference in how Tomcat and JBoss set up contexts for loading resources.  Have a look at this question for some alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10833046/load-resource-returns-null-with-jboss7

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Austin.  Now that I know about JBoss Modules I've done some research and I can now read the file.  However, in the article you linked to we are putting the data file in .\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules\com\mycompany\configuration\main.  module.xml has the path="." so the data file must be in the same folder.  Can you tell me what this Path is relative to?  For example if I want the data file to be placed in .\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments\projectname.war\WEB-INF, how would I set the Path?  (Where would I find that answer?)  Thanks, Al.